# Running DOS COMMAND on SQlcmd does not work

Tags: sqlcmd

Hi I am trying execute the DOS COMMAND on sqlcmd on a DOS TERMINAL but it simply does not return anything even error.

When I execute it on SSMS it works.

Do you know that is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the problem.
The problem is: I have to version on my machine 32 bit and 64 bit, by default when I open the DOS PROMPT and run the sqlcmd it assumes the 32 bit version. As my OS is 64 bit the 32 bit does not work.

So I just renamed the sqlcmd 32 bit on the folder the it is in. Now when I open the prompt and run the sqlcmd the 64 bit comes to play and every command started with :!! works.

Comment: I tried with 64 bit, newest version (15.0.1000.34 NT), adjusted path, double-checked it is 64 bit version - same thing. "!!" shell commands do not work on version 14.x and up. You need to use sqlcmd version lower than 14, or separate shell commands into separate bat file and interchangeably run sql and bat files.